# Docker file update volume

Tags: docker, elixir

Hello I have a project in elixir, but I have doubts about how I can make a link whenever I update my files locally update the docker,
so you don't have to use docker-compose up every time something is updated.

my docker file :

```
    FROM elixir:alpine
    
    RUN apk add --update --no-cache curl py-pip
    RUN apk add --no-cache build-base git
    
    WORKDIR /app
    
    RUN mix local.hex --force && \
            mix local.rebar --force
    
    COPY mix.exs mix.lock ./
    COPY config config
    
    RUN mix do deps.get, deps.compile
    
    COPY priv priv
    COPY lib lib
    
    COPY numbers.csv numbers.csv
    
    COPY docker-entrypoint.sh docker-entrypoint.sh
    
    EXPOSE 4000

docker-compose:

version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
      restart: on-failure
      build: .
      command: /bin/sh docker-entrypoint.sh
      ports: 
        - "4000:4000"
      depends_on: 
        - postgres-db 
      links:
        - postgres-db
      env_file:
        - .env
  postgres-db:
      image: "postgres:12"
      restart: always
      container_name: "postgres-db"
      environment: 
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
        POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
        POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      ports: 
        - "5432:5432"
```

folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have another docker-compose file called `docker-compose.override.yml` which is your setup for local development. In that file, you can use `volumes` to get local file updates being reflected in the docker container (while it's running):

It will look something like this (look at the `volumes` part):

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13.0
    env_file:
      - ./docker/dev.env
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  spiritpay:
    image: spiritpay:local
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    env_file:
      - ./docker/dev.env
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
      - "4002:4002"
    volumes:
      - /opt/spiritpay/assets/node_modules
      - ./assets:/opt/spiritpay/assets
      - ./config:/opt/spiritpay/config:ro
      - ./lib:/opt/spiritpay/lib:ro
      - ./priv:/opt/spiritpay/priv
      - ./test:/opt/spiritpay/test:ro
      - ./mix.exs:/opt/spiritpay/mix.exs:ro
      - ./mix.lock:/opt/spiritpay/mix.lock:ro

volumes:
  db-data:
```

Comment: Hello could you help me how could i run docker-compose.override.yml? because I have 2 docker-compose and I don't know how to run it on the docker.

Comment: Yes, no problem. Just use docker-compose like normal. It will prefer to use the override file.